# How to find long running PHP script

Tags: php, apache

Is there a neat way to get some metrics on script runtimes with Apache?

I'd like to find the longest running php script on my website (mean, median, ..). Since I have more than 50 scripts I wanted to know if there is some automated way to find the slowest script.

Some metrics concerning includes would also be nice. Which script recursively includes the most others? etc

I have SSH access to my webserver running Ubuntu server 14.04. Maybe there is some local application that helps benchmarking my scripts that I don't know about?

Comment: I think you need to logs PHP to see if recursivity, variables, initialisations, functions, declaration, loop ...
https://bugs.php.net/bugs-getting-valgrind-log.php

Comment: SO is about coding, not managing web servers unless it has to do with a development environment.

Comment: If you have full access to your PHP install then look into the directives: [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and [`auto_append_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file). In the prepend file; `<?php $ultimate_start = microtime(true);`. In the append file; `<?php echo __file__.': '.(microtime(true) - $ultimate_start).' seconds';`. I'm sure you can figure out how to make the append file write data to a log ;-)

Comment: If you do not have full access to your PHP install then you will have to manually include the benchmarking code into your scripts; just be cognizant of scripts which include other scripts because that will screw up the variable `$ultimate_start`. You can use `require_once()` to circumvent the aforementioned issue.